# in cypress, intercept in test doesn't work

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm starting to use cypress and I wanted to do 2 test. One to verify what is displayed if my api return 'false' and one to what is on screen if my api return 'true'.
I tried to do a simple test like this one :

```
context('contextTest', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.waitLoading();
  });
  beforeEach(() => {});

  it('false test', function() {
    cy.intercept('POST', '**/test/alreadySent', {
      fixture: 'test/alreadySent-false.json',
    }).as('alreadySent');

    cy.wait('@alreadySent');
    cy.get('[data-cy=alreadysent-button]');
  });
});
```

But the intercept doesn't work and it always return the true api call.
What is strange is, if I just put the code in my before(), all work fine as expected.

```
context('contextTest', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.intercept('POST', '**/test/alreadySent', {
      fixture: 'test/alreadySent-false.json',
    }).as('alreadySent');

    cy.waitLoading();
  });
  beforeEach(() => {});

  it('false test', function() {
    cy.wait('@alreadySent');
    cy.get('[data-cy=alreadysent-button]');
  });
});
```

But I need to change the intercept for the next test so I wanted to set the intercept on this test exclusively.

Is it possible, why is my first code doesn't seem to work?
Or should I write my next test on another file and it is a bad practice to do this kind of verification on the same file?

Answer (score 5):

Since it works when the intercept is moved up in the command order, it seems that `cy.waitLoading()` triggers the POST and not `cy.get('[data-cy=alreadysent-button]')`.

The intercept must always be set up before the trigger (page visit or button click).

But the intercept varies between tests, so instead of `before()` I would try setting up a helper function that is called at the top of each test.

```js
const loadAndIntercept = (apiResult) => {     
  const apiFixture = apiResult ? 'test/alreadySent-true.json' : 'test/alreadySent-false.json';
  cy.intercept('POST', '**/test/alreadySent', { fixture: apiFixture }).as('alreadySent');
  cy.waitLoading();
})

it('false test', function() {
  loadAndIntercept(false);
  cy.wait('@alreadySent');
  cy.get('[data-cy=alreadysent-button]');
});

it('true test', function() {
  loadAndIntercept(true);
  cy.wait('@alreadySent');
  cy.get('[data-cy=alreadysent-button]');
});
```

This should work since intercepts are cleared between tests. Ref [docs - intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Usage)

> Note: all intercepts are automatically cleared before every test.

Comment: You were exacly right. it was obviously the waitLoading who waited for the loading of the page, so of course the test wasn't run at all and intercept came too late... Sry for disturbing, it work well and I like your idea of the function Thanks !